# How to prevent the second site with apache2 from serving root folders

Tags: apache2, root, wordpress, vps, websites

I am setting a VPS with one IP adress to serve multiple websites. The first one is running. The second only shows an Index of / listing the two folders containing files of the two websites within the default DocumentRoot /var/www/html. When I click on the site folder it gives me a shadow html version of the site (no images, no content, no links working).How can I force the second sebsite to be served from the folder already defined in the .conf file?

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 5 and Apache 2. Both websites wordpress latest version.

First website (running) firstsite.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@firstsite.com
    ServerName firstsite.com
    ServerAlias www.firstsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/firstsite
 <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/firstsite>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Second website (not running) secondsite.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@secondsite.com
    ServerName secondsite.com
    ServerAlias www.secondsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secondsite
 <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/secondsite>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I expect to output the frontend of the website secondsite.com, but the actual output is:

```
Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[DIR]   firstsite/  2019-04-28 17:00    -    
[DIR]   secondsite/ 2013-09-25 00:18    -
```

Comment: It sounds like you have installed Wordpress to some other folder than `/var/www/html/secondsite`. What is the content of `test/` and `example/`? Are they actually present at `/var/www/html/secondsite`?

Comment: sorry for the typping error, I have edited it: both folders firstsite and secondsite are correctly installed with wordpress. Each one of them is respectively the main folder DocumentRoot as configured in .conf

Comment: It's basically matching default vhost then, which has `/var/www/html` as root. Is the config correct? No typos? Does `sudo systemctl -u apache2` show any warnings?

Comment: the command `sudo systemctl -u apache2`
gives  `systemctl: invalid option -- 'u' `

Comment: Sorry. `sudo journalctl -u apache2`

Comment: two repetitive warnings  `[alias:warn] [pid 2900] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.` and `Apr 28 20:01:53 *.*.*.* systemd[1]:apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 28 20:01:53 *.*.*.* systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 28 20:01:53 *.*.*.* systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.`

Comment: and at the end:  `AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/var/www/html/secondsite] does not exist` and
`AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/var/www/html/firstsite] does not exist`

Comment: Is your config **actually** as you have posted, or are you missing `/` in front of `var/www[...]` in the configs?

Comment: the `/` is well there before `var/www[...]` [see here](https://imgur.com/a/nu3td9q)